# Error installing ubuntu on HP notebook

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hp

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my HP notebook and it keeps on failing. I first tryied installing ubuntu 21.10 and it kept on giving me an error that it failed to install grub. When I tried to install 22.04 it just kept showing an internal error that the installer crashed.
My HP also has windows installed but the Ubuntu installer does not recognize that there is windows already installed.
In some cases it messes up my boot system and I have to create a recovery drive so I can boot into windows.

Comment: Can you edit your post and add whether you were able to start ubuntu in live mode?

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a MUST. Start by doing that and shutdown instead of reboot to make the setting stick. Then open UEFI settings and disable Legacy/CSM ("UEFI only" is the setting you want) to assure booting and installing in the proper UEFI mode. Giving this conditions the Ubuntu installer should (1) detect Windows and (2) use the preexisting EFI partition to install the bootloader. Also prepare your system from Windows by making enough unallocated space for Ubuntu > shrink Windows partition. (...)

Comment: Not knowing the aforementioned details and not being familiar with your own firmware (UEFI) is NOT an option.